# GPG key errors for for older releases

Tags: apt, 9.04

```
W: GPG error: http  //archive.ubuntu.com jaunty Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 2
W: Failed to fetch http:  //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/Release.gpg  Error reading from server - read (104 Connection reset by peer) [IP: 91.189.92.170 80]

W: Failed to fetch http:  //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Error reading from server - read (104 Connection reset by peer) [IP: 91.189.92.170 80]

W: Failed to fetch http:  //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Error reading from server - read (104 Connection reset by peer) [IP: 91.189.92.170 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

I tried as per the instructions but it gave follwoing errors again on doing restore default it is showing null as during updateion from 9.04 to 9.10  in that process i delte the earlier keys ;-

how shall i retrive gpg keys for jaunty

```
Hit http: //archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/universe Sources                  
Hit http: //archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/main Sources                      
Hit http: //archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/multiverse Sources                
Fetched 598B in 6s (88B/s)                                                     
W: GPG error: http: //security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 2
W: GPG error: http: //archive.ubuntu.com jaunty Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 2
W: GPG error: http: //archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 2
W: Failed to fetch http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Error reading from server - read (104 Connection reset by peer) [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

W: Failed to fetch http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Error reading from server - read (104 Connection reset by peer) [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

W: Failed to fetch http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Error reading from server - read (104 Connection reset by peer) [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

W: Failed to fetch http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Error reading from server - read (104 Connection reset by peer) [IP: 91.189.92.171 80]

W: Failed to fetch http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Error reading from server - read (104 Connection reset by peer) [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

With regard to the "Failed to fetch" warnings, this is related to the 18-month EOL of Jaunty. The package repositories have moved to another server - from `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. Try changing the your `/etc/apt/sources.list` accordingly, as shown in the `sources.list` in this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Jaunty

You don't need to actually upgrade your release, just change the APT sources.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 9.04 a.k.a. "Jaunty" has been end-of-life [since last month](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2010-September/000137.html).  I suspect the error you see is related to that...

You should upgrade your system to a newer release to ensure you keep getting security updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- Restore the default keys in Synaptic (Settings-->Administration-->Synaptic Package Manager)
- In Synaptic Package Manager go to Settings-->Repositories
- It will open software sources,go to Authentication tab and click restore defaults.

[image]

And then type the following in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get update
```

I hope this will solve your problem.If you have any problems let me know through comments.